# For..In Loop Overwriting ALL Array Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects, for-in-loop

I'm trying to use a for..in loop to iterate through a list of names, add them to a template object ('group'), then add each complete object to an array ('queryList'). This isn't working because each iteration is overwriting ALL values in the array. Any suggestions why this is happening?

```
// BATTERY OBJECT
var groupList = [ "LOGIN", "BROWSE", "SEARCH"];

// GROUP OBJECT
var group = {dbName: 'CARS', name: '', collectionName: 'group'};

// INIT VARS
var groupName = '',
    queryList = [];

// COMPILATION FUNCTION
var buildGroupQueries = function(group){

    // BUILD BATCH OF QUERIES   
    for (var i in groupList){
        groupName = groupList[i];
        group.name = groupName;
        queryList[i] = group;
    }
    console.log(queryList);

}

buildGroupQueries(group);
```

It should look like:

```
[
    {"dbName":"CARS","name":"LOGIN","collectionName":"group"},
    {"dbName":"CARS","name":"BROWSE","collectionName":"group"},
    {"dbName":"CARS","name":"SEARCH","collectionName":"group"}
]
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
[
    {"dbName":"CARS","name":"SEARCH","collectionName":"group"},
    {"dbName":"CARS","name":"SEARCH","collectionName":"group"},
    {"dbName":"CARS","name":"SEARCH","collectionName":"group"}
]
```

Comment: The problem is with `queryList[i] = group;`.  Look at that `i`.  Can you set `queryList["LOGIN"]` to a value?  Or maybe queryList needs to be initialized as a dictionary?  I may just avoid using `in` until I better understand what I'm doing with those variables.

Comment: The problem is not at all with the `in` statement, the problem is that `group` is a reference and is not copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an array of elements referring to the same object, so they all show the same name coinciding with the last time you changed it, which is "SEARCH" in your example.
You have to refer each element to a new object created from the one you want to use as a template.
To do so you can either loop over its properties or clone it as shown below:

```
// BATTERY OBJECT
var groupList = [ "LOGIN", "BROWSE", "SEARCH"];

// GROUP OBJECT
var group = {dbName: 'CARS', name: '', collectionName: 'group'};

// INIT VARS
var groupName = '',
    queryList = [];

// COMPILATION FUNCTION
var buildGroupQueries = function(group){
    var i, _group;

    // BUILD BATCH OF QUERIES
    for (i in groupList){
        _group        = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(group));
        groupName     = groupList[i];
        _group.name   = groupName;
        queryList[i]  = _group;
    }
    console.log(queryList);

}

buildGroupQueries(group);
```

Comment: I'm accepting your answer. It's clear, concise and has full example code. I should've been more mindful that objects are passed as references not values. Thanks Luca!

Answer (score 2):

You modify the `group` object each time, but you need to modify its copy.

Add this code just after your line `for (var i in groupList){`

```
var _group = {};
for (var j in group){ _group[j] = group[j]; }
```

On each iteration you create a new object and copy to it all properties from the master object.

Comment: Ah, I see. That should've been obvious haha. I'm passing the object by reference, not value. Thanks man!